# How do I create a new MySQL table as a subset of the fields from the primary table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 30 fields. I need to create a second table with a subset of those fields, plus the CURDATE() to track the history of their spending. I'm getting syntax errors, but perhaps my method is incorrect to begin with. Please review this, thanks!

```
INSERT INTO history (customer_id, name, amount, date_recorded)
set date_recorded = CURDATE()
SELECT customer_id, name, amount
FROM master;
```

What I'm attempting to do in MySQL in the above example is copy the fields of customer_id, name, amount from the master customer list, and include today's date. The record layout for the history table is here:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| customer_id   | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| name          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_recorded | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
INSERT INTO history (customer_id, name, amount, date_recorded)

SELECT customer_id, name, amount, CURDATE()
FROM master
```

One more way is ::

```
INSERT INTO history (customer_id, name, amount, date_recorded)

SELECT customer_id, name, amount, DATE(now())
FROM master
```

Comment: Thanks for the posting. Wouldn't the CURDATE() on the select search for the current date in the master?
I tried the above, it returned this with no changes:
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: No it doesnt need to, it will will fetch the values for column name :
customer_id, name, amount, and the `CURDATE()` will return the date from the system..

Comment: Got it! My mistake, I had re-created the table without re-populating my test table. Works now, and also thank you for your explanation!

Comment: So how is the date from CURDATE() getting transferred to the value of date_recorded? Does MySQL pay attention to the order from the INSERT line? Thanks!